# Thread reports dead after KeyboardInterrupt in thread.join()

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, interrupt, cpython, keyboardinterrupt

The code:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def f() -> None:
    while True:
        sleep(0.4)
        print("Thread is running.")

thread = Thread(target=f, daemon=True)
thread.start()

try:
    thread.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt")

sleep(0.8)
print(f"thread._is_stopped = {thread._is_stopped}")
print(f"thread.is_alive() = {thread.is_alive()}")
sleep(0.8)
```

`thread._is_stopped` is set to `True` and `thread.is_alive()` reports `False` even though the thread is still alive and printing out messages to the console. This is the output:

```
python3 test.py
Thread is running.
Thread is running.
Thread is running.
^CCaught KeyboardInterrupt
Thread is running.
Thread is running.
thread._is_stopped = True
thread.is_alive() = False
Thread is running.
Thread is running.
```

Why is `.is_alive()` and `._is_stopped` reporting that the thread is dead when the thread is clearly alive? Also if I `.join()` the thread again, it immediately returns which is undesirable for me.

Replacing the `thread.join()` with `sleep(100)`, fixes the problem with `is_alive()` reporting `False`. The problem is that I want to know immediately when the thread really exists.

System:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2
- python 3.10.6 (pre-installed with Ubuntu)
- running it from `bash` (IDLE has problems with even causing a `KeyboardInterrupt`s when joining a thread)

Comment: I found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue46726) on python's bug tracker.